# Difference between who and whoami commands

Tags: command-line, who, whoami

The man page description of `who` command is 
`who - show who is logged on`

But there exists a similar command `whoami`. The man page description of `whoami` is

`whoami - print effective userid`

Can anyone explain what exactly these commands do ? How are they different from each other ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am logging in as root in my shell and typing `who` and this is the output.

```
who
root     tty1         2014-08-25 14:01 (:0)
root     pts/0        2014-09-05 10:22 (:0.0)
root     pts/3        2014-09-19 10:08 (xxx.xxx.edu)
```

It effectively shows all the users that have established a connection.

```
ssh ramesh@hostname
```

Running `who` again will result in another entry for the user ramesh.

```
who
root     tty1         2014-08-25 14:01 (:0)
root     pts/0        2014-09-05 10:22 (:0.0)
root     pts/3        2014-09-19 10:08 (xxx.xxx.edu)
ramesh   pts/4        2014-09-19 12:11 (xxx.xxx.edu)
```

Inside the `root` shell, I just do `su ramesh` and then run `whoami`. It will give me the current user, ramesh, as the output.

Effectively, `who` gives the list of all users currently logged in on the machine and with `whoami` you can know the current user who is in the shell.

Answer (score 7):

`who`: Print information about users who are currently logged in.

`whoami`: Print effective username of the user who ran `whoami`.

For example:

```
mohsen@debian:~$ who ## list logged in usernames
mohsen   :0           2014-09-19 16:31 (:0)
mohsen   pts/0        2014-09-19 16:32 (:0)
mohsen   pts/1        2014-09-19 19:42 (:0)

mohsen@debian:~$ whoami 
mohsen                        ##### print my username (mohsen)
mohsen@debian:~$
```

I also recommend a command better than `who`, the [`w`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/w.1.html) command. Its output is:

```
mohsen@debian:~$ w
 21:45:45 up  5:16,  3 users,  load average: 0.68, 0.54, 0.46
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mohsen   :0       :0               16:31   ?xdm?   1:40m  0.27s gdm-session-wor
mohsen   pts/0    :0               16:32    1.00s  0.15s  0.01s w
mohsen   pts/1    :0               19:42    2:03m  0.13s 14.06s /usr/bin/python
```

**See Also :**

[`last`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html) command, `/var/log/btmp` and `/var/log/wtmp` files.

Answer (score 2):

Note on the difference between `who` and `whoami`.

The `who` command will always display the account that you used to login (the real user info).

The `whoami` command will show your effective user.

For example,
if you login as "blammy",
the `who` and `whoami` commands will display something like this:

```
> who
blammy  pts/0  2011-04-23 13:43 (123.23.123.123)

> whoami
blammy
```

This indicates that user "blammy" logged in on 23 Apr 2011 at 13:43 from ip "123.23.123.123".

If you then run `su - kapow`,
you change your effective user to be "kapow".

Now,
the `who` and `whoami` commands will display something like this:

```
> who
blammy  pts/0  2011-04-23 13:43 (123.23.123.123)

> whoami
kapow
```

Notice that the `who` info stays the same,
but the `whoami` info changes based on the su.